# Running Multibit on Tails - connecting error

Tags: privacy, multibit

I'm trying to get Multibit wallet set up on my new Tails USB. It's up and running, but isn't able to connect to the internet. It just says "Connecting" in red.

The message log says this -

```
http://www.multibit.org/help_contents.html   Loading...
Unable to load "http://www.multibit.org/help_contents.html". The error was 
"java.net.ConnectException Connection refused".
```

I'm guessing I need to configure something and perhaps launch Multibit from the command line rather than clicking the icon but I'm new to both Tails and Multibit.

Does anyone have any experience or pointers as to what I need to enable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an error on your side, but rather Multibit's inability to connect to www.multibit.org in order to retrieve that URL. Do you have unfettered Internet access? Could you be behind a firewall? Can you hit `http://www.multibit.org/help_contents.html` within a browser? It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

TAILS doesn't automagically run all traffic through tor.  Included programs are pre-configured to do so and it prevents anything not using tor from connecting out (hence your "connection refused" error), but you still need to configure anything you installed after the fact to use the tor proxy.

Go into the settings in multibit and set it to connect through a socks4 proxy and point it at 127.0.0.1 port 9050.

Comment: ah HA! I had a feeling it was proxy related.